# React Native App crashes when i open it on my real android device with no errors on console in emulator

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, crash-reports

I am building a react native app, when i first started the build after i completed 2 screens of it, i created the apk file and installed it on my device, it opened perfectly without any crash. But now that i almost have it complete, it is crashing after the splash screen, i am installing it on an HTC desire 10 pro which has android 6.0 on it.

what i tried is debugg it if it has any error by opening the JS debugger from expo on my android studio device but no errors are shown on screen. Can you please help me to know what might be the problem with it ?
do i need to delete package-lock.json ?

here is my package.json:

```
`{
    "name": "f1ian",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
        "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "expo": "~48.0.18",
        "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
        "expo-web-browser": "^12.1.1",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.71.8",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
    },
    "private": true
}`
```

here is my eas file:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.6.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

app.json file

```
{
    "expo": {
        "name": "f1ian",
        "slug": "f1ian",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./App/assets/icon.png",
        "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
        "splash": {
            "image": "./App/assets/splash.png",
            "resizeMode": "contain",
            "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        "updates": {
            "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
        },
        "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
        "ios": {
            "supportsTablet": true
        },
        "android": {
            "package": "com.f1ian.f1ian",
            "versionCode": 1,
            "adaptiveIcon": {
                "foregroundImage": "./App/assets/adaptive-icon.png",
                "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
            }
        },
        "web": {
            "favicon": "./App/assets/favicon.png"
        },
        "extra": {
            "eas": {
                "projectId": "f5f4f061-dc1b-46a3-9474-4ce7f3c8dc36"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that in the last screen i built, "Platform" wasn't imported from "react-native". So to anyone who is facing this issue, look at the imports.